# Update a 2D list from another file.py - Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, chess

this is my problem:
I have a table.py that rapresent all the positions, with a specific value that chess pieces can assume, for example
Table.py

```
PAWN = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Initially is all 0

In another file, Update.py, i get from a list, all the moves that were made, for example "g3, e4, etc"
what i do here is a check

```
for moves in game_moves: 
    if len(moves) == 2: #It is a Pawn, first move is g3, so moves[0] = g, moves[1] = 3 
        if moves[0]=='g':
            x = int(moves[1])
            print("old table value: " +str(table.PAWN[6][x])) #----> this is 0, Right
            table.PAWN[6][x] =+ delta #delta is a value of 0,1
            print("new table value: " +str(table.PAWN[6][x])) #----> this is 0,1 Right
```

But in Table.py, the g3 square remains 0, it doesnt update to 0,1. Why?

Comment: The code runs and manipulate objects, it don't change the files that were initially used. If you have `a=5`, and the code says `a=6` the file won't change

Comment: so i need something like update a?

Comment: Please give more code,such as the code near definition of `PAWN` and code near where you call update-move function.

Comment: Do you expect the file to change at the end ? Like when the program ends the file has changed ?

Comment: yes i expect the table of PAWN updated, from 0 to 0,1